# Trying to calculate a value from multiple mathematical formulas in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, math

I'm new to PHP you will see why in the code below. I'm trying to convert a string to only numbers, then multiply every number according to its position and then sum all up to one variable and divide it by 11 in the end. But end up getting a too big of a value in the end.

It all starts with getting a string of 17 letters and numbers, which will be converted only to numbers:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    


    if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
    {

        //$_SESSION['count']=0;

    }
    ?>
    <form action="" method="POST">
  <i> VIN-nummer: </i><input type="text" name="fvin">
  <input type="submit" value="Ber&auml;kna" name="submit">
  <br></br>
</form>

<?php
$fvin = $_POST['fvin'];

$l2n = array(
    'A'=>'1',
    'B'=>'2',
    'C'=>'3',
    'D'=>'4',
    'E'=>'5',
    'F'=>'6',
    'G'=>'7',
    'H'=>'8',
    'J'=>'1',
    'K'=>'2',
    'L'=>'3',
    'M'=>'4',
    'N'=>'5',
    'P'=>'7',
    'R'=>'9',
    'S'=>'2',
    'T'=>'3',
    'U'=>'4',
    'V'=>'5',
    'W'=>'6',
    'X'=>'7',
    'Y'=>'8',
    'Z'=>'9'
);

$keys = array_keys($l2n);
$values = array_values($l2n);
$evin = str_replace($keys, $values, $fvin);
```

I have echoed the results and so far so good! Then for the "broken" part. For every position a number is in, it will be multiplied with a specific number e.g:

- Position 0 needs to be multiplied with 8
- Position 1 needs to be multiplied with 7
- Position 2 needs to be multiplied with 6...

```
$fvin0 = substr($evin, 0, 0). $fvin0 *=8;
$fvin1 = substr($evin, 1, 1). $fvin1 *=7;
$fvin2 = substr($evin, 2, 2). $fvin2 *=6;
$fvin3 = substr($evin, 3, 3). $fvin3 *=5;
$fvin4 = substr($evin, 4, 4). $fvin4 *=4;
$fvin5 = substr($evin, 5, 5). $fvin5 *=3;
$fvin6 = substr($evin, 6, 6). $fvin6 *=2;
$fvin7 = substr($evin, 7, 7). $fvin7 *=10;
$fvin8 = substr($evin, 8, 8);
$fvin9 = substr($evin, 9, 9). $fvin9 *=9;
$fvin10 = substr($evin, 10, 10). $fvin10 *=8;
$fvin11 = substr($evin, 11, 11). $fvin11 *=7;
$fvin12 = substr($evin, 12, 12). $fvin12 *=6;
$fvin13 = substr($evin, 13, 13). $fvin13 *=5;
$fvin14 = substr($evin, 14, 14). $fvin14 *=4;
$fvin15 = substr($evin, 15, 15). $fvin15 *=3;
$fvin16 = substr($evin, 16, 16). $fvin16 *=2;
```

Every number will be multiplied with a number except position 8.

Then sum everything together up and divide it by 11.

```
$fvin += ($fvin0 + $fvin1 + $fvin2 + $fvin3 + $fvin4 + $fvin5 + $fvin6 + $fvin7 + $fvin8 + $fvin9 + $fvin10 + $fvin11 + $fvin12 + $fvin13 + $fvin14 + $fvin15 + $fvin16)/11;


if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    echo $fvin;
    echo "<br>";
    
}
```

I've done the math on paper and I get too big of a number. Also here's an example of what string I start with: VRZUA5FX29J276031, and should end up with 42,363636... but end up with 94405436.6363...

I know my code is a bit messy but any help would make my day!

Comment: Please go and enable proper PHP error reporting! This should have given you a lot of "undefined variable" warnings - because you are using the _concatenation operator_ in there, `$fvin0 = substr($evin, 0, 0). $fvin0 *=8;` - you are trying to _append_ the value of `$fvin0 *=8` to the result of the `substr` call, _before_ `$fvin0` even got any value assigned.

Comment: And why are you increasing the value of the `$length` parameter of `substr` each time?

Comment: Thank You for your feedback @CBroe ! In my other smaller projects I had PHP error logs enabled and that helped me, I don't know why I didn't use it here. I guess I just thought I was good enough now but... Every $fvin0,1,2,3... had errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be concatenating `$fvin<num> *= multiplier` to each value. Since you haven't assigned anything to any of those `$fvin` variables yet, you're multiplying 0, and then appending that 0 to the substring of `$evin`. You should be multiplying the substring by those multipliers.

The second argument to `substr()` is the length of the substring, not the index of the end of the substring. These should all be 1.

```
$fvin0 = substr($evin, 0, 1) * 8;
$fvin1 = substr($evin, 1, 1) * 7;
$fvin2 = substr($evin, 2, 1) * 6;
$fvin3 = substr($evin, 3, 1) * 5;
$fvin4 = substr($evin, 4, 1) * 4;
$fvin5 = substr($evin, 5, 1) * 3;
$fvin6 = substr($evin, 6, 1) * 2;
$fvin7 = substr($evin, 7, 1) * 10;
$fvin8 = substr($evin, 8, 1);
$fvin9 = substr($evin, 9, 1) * 9;
$fvin10 = substr($evin, 10, 1) * 8;
$fvin11 = substr($evin, 11, 1) * 7;
$fvin12 = substr($evin, 12, 1) * 6;
$fvin13 = substr($evin, 13, 1) * 5;
$fvin14 = substr($evin, 14, 1) * 4;
$fvin15 = substr($evin, 15, 1) * 3;
$fvin16 = substr($evin, 16, 1) * 2;
```

Comment: Thank You! It works now. I guess I didn't read enough about `substr()`. I thought it was the end of the substring. I don't know anything about "concatenating" so that's something I have to read more about.

Comment: Just one more thing... Won't `$fvin` be assigned first when it's the first thing in the line? So in the future I need make sure to assign variables before I try to do anything with them. But how would I do this in this case? Could I assign  `$fvin0 = substr($evin, 0, 1)` and afterwards multiply it  `$fvin0 * 8`  ?

Comment: Everything to the right of `=` is calculated first, then assigned to the variable.

Comment: Yes, you could do it in 2 statements. But why do that?

Comment: The `.` operator is for concatenating strings. Why did you write it if you didn't know what it does?

Comment: I tried different things and nothing worked, so I tried a few things from the internet where someone used `.`. Got desperate and got the close to my "goal". I guess my method of trying things without reading about what it actually does is not a good way to solve your own code.